# Detect blurred part of an image

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

I have an image in the image view. When user taps on the image, it makes a part of the image blur. This part is working fine (as expected). But, if the part if already blurred then I do not want it to be blurred further. Can you give me a clue on how it can be achieved ?  Consider any general image.

Comment: It seems like the only way to do so is to save the blurred areas somewhere and apply it each time when user taps on image. I mean apply it to original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either keep the original image and the blurred image separately as Alexander suggests, or keep a mask that lets you track what parts of the image have already been blurred, and mask away the already-blurred areas before applying your blur filter again.

Comment: Yeah, I used both the ideas i.e. Alexander's and your's. Amm, I created a object with attributes as CGPoint and CIImage. Kept on saving the tapped point and the blurred image. And created array of the class instance. Then on a press of a "Apply" button, I applied all the image transformation. It's little heavy but working towards it. Cheers mate. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the image have to blur by being touched or can it just look like it is?  What if you loaded the original image on top of a blurred version of the image and erased the top layer on touch?  Kind of renders your blurring function useless though.

It's a pretty hacky way to do it, but unless you want to keep track of a list of every pixel that was altered like Alexander said, I can't think of another way.  That way you can just apply the blur to the already unaffected ones.

Comment: Or put the blurred image on top of the non-blurred image as a CALayer with a mask layer attached, fully masking the blurred layer to transparent, and as the user taps/drags, draw circles in the mask to expose the blur layer.

Comment: totally viable as well